# A quick way to test equality of more than 2 values at once?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was a quick way to test the equality of more than two values in js. Something similar to (= 6 6 6).

In the console, I tried things like...

```
1 == 1 == 1 == 1
true
2 == 2 == 2 == 2
false
0 == 0 == 0
false
0 == 0 == 0 == 0
true
```

...which was amusing, but also puzzling.

Is there a quick way of doing this in js?

Thanks.

Comment: Why? This sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242). What bigger problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you got unexpected behavior is because we need to adjust your expectations in js a bit ;)  `2 == 2 == 2 == 2` does 3 comparisons, all from left to right.  The first comparison is the leftmost `2 == 2`, which evaluates to true.  After that we get the result of the first comparison being compared to (what is in this case) the 3rd `2`.  Ie, `true === 2`, which is false.  And finally, we get `false === 2`, which is also false.

It might help to visualize it as such:

(((2 == 2) == 2) == 2)

I think in general `a === b && b === c` might be what you're looking for.

*EDIT*: Ah, and sorry I keep switching out the `==` for `===`.  It's just habit.  And it's a habit I'd recommend.  the `===` operator doesn't do type casting, so it evaluates the value proper, not a casted version of the value.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `true == 1` but `true != 2`

You can try:

```
function isEquals() {
 var flag = true;
 for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) flag = flag && (arguments[i] == arguments[0]);
  return flag;
}
isEquals(2,2,2); // true
```

or:

```
function isEquals() {
 var ar = arguments;
 return Array.prototype.every.call(arguments, function(a){return a==ar[0];});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you need to use the "Logical Operators" like the && or || to check more than 1 statement like (x<1 && y>0).
You can use this as a quick easy reference: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than three values, it might be more convenient to create a function for use on an array:

```
function allEqual(arr) {
    return arr.every(function (x, i) {
        return i === 0 || x === arr[i - 1];
    });
}

allEqual([1, 1, 1])
```

ES6:

```
function allEqual(...arr) {
    return arr.every((x, i) => i === 0 || x === arr[i - 1]);
}

allEqual(1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: You could use it with the `arguments` array(ish) too by replacing `arr.every(f)` with `Array.prototype.every.call(arguments, f);`

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @vp_arth's answer you could even add a method to the Array prototype

```
Array.prototype.isHomogeneous = function(){
    return Array.prototype.every.call(this, function(c,i,a){ return c === a[0];})
}
```

So you could do

`[1,2,3].isHomogeneous()`  = false

`[1,1,1].isHomogeneous()`  = true